# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps logging out after crash

Tags: ubuntu

Recently I have installed new Ubuntu 18.04 and made minor set ups. But, it keeps logging out after certain actions made. Namely, I have installed google chrome browser and restored previous ubuntu 15.04 browser data and extensions. When I want to download video or something via downloader extension, the system stops and throws me back to log in view. After Loging back, all windows and applications are closed. The same this occurs if I want to remove or run installation of some applications. My suggestion is that, it keeps logging out if system faces some errors. Need your help. Thank you beforehand

This is detailed logs when this happened:

```
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20860]: dbus-update-activation-environment: setting _=/usr/bin/dbus-update-activation-environment
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.6' (uid=1000 pid=20869 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-binary --sess" label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.9' (uid=1000 pid=20953 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-acceler" label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa systemd[20842]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa at-spi-bus-launcher[20962]: dbus-daemon[20967]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=20953 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-session-check-acceler" label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa at-spi-bus-launcher[20962]: dbus-daemon[20967]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa at-spi-bus-launcher[20962]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop[20979]: SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20860]: (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "BOE", prod id 1608
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20860]: (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20860]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  141.40  1920 1968 2000 2142  1080 1083 1089 1100 +hsync -vsync (66.0 kHz eP)
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[20860]: (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x0.0  113.12  1920 1968 2000 2142  1080 1083 1089 1100 +hsync -vsync (52.8 kHz e)
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Successfully made thread 20994 of process 20994 (n/a) owned by '1000' high priority at nice level -11.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Supervising 1 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Successfully made thread 20995 of process 20994 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Supervising 2 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Successfully made thread 20996 of process 20994 (n/a) owned by '1000' RT at priority 5.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa rtkit-daemon[1127]: Supervising 3 threads of 1 processes of 1 users.
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa bluetoothd[843]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.17910 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa bluetoothd[843]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.17910 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink
Aug  2 20:39:15 sa pulseaudio[20994]: [pulseaudio] backend-ofono.c: Failed to register as a handsfree audio agent with ofono: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.ofono was not provided by any .service files
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.portal.IBus' requested by ':1.16' (uid=1000 pid=21007 comm="ibus-daemon --xim --panel disable " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.portal.IBus'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5' unit='evolution-source-registry.service' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=21027 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Evolution source registry...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.21' (uid=1000 pid=21031 comm="/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-source-registry " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Sources5'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Evolution source registry.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa goa-daemon[21039]: goa-daemon version 3.28.0 starting
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.CalendarServer'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='org.gnome.Identity' requested by ':1.22' (uid=1000 pid=21039 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/goa-daemon " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.OnlineAccounts'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Identity'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.GeoClue2' unit='geoclue.service' requested by ':1.17906' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[1]: Starting Location Lookup Service...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='ca.desrt.dconf' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.GeoClue2'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[1]: Started Location Lookup Service.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa wpa_supplicant[840]: dbus: fill_dict_with_properties dbus_interface=fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1.Interface dbus_property=Stations getter failed
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa gnome-shell[20985]: Telepathy is not available, chat integration will be disabled.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-udisks2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service - disk device monitor.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-goa-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service - GNOME Online Accounts monitor.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-afc-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa gvfs-afc-volume-monitor[21070]: Volume monitor alive
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Apple File Conduit monitor.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-mtp-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service - Media Transfer Protocol monitor.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' unit='gvfs-gphoto2-volume-monitor.service' requested by ':1.13' (uid=1000 pid=20985 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor...
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem service - digital camera monitor.
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa spice-vdagent[21112]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa gnome-shell[20985]: JS WARNING: [/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/appIcons.js 1027]: unreachable code after return statement
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa gnome-session[20869]: gnome-session-binary[20869]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa gnome-session-binary[20869]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.17918' (uid=1000 pid=21089 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-rfkill " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:16 sa systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-sharing[21095]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-sharing[21095]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-sharing[21095]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-xsettings[21108]: Failed to get current display configuration state: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NameHasNoOwner: Name "org.gnome.Mutter.DisplayConfig" does not exist
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-xsettings[21108]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-power[21085]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-clipboard[21121]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-color[21122]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-media-keys[21133]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-keyboard[21130]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-wacom[21115]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gnome-session-binary[20869]: Entering running state
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa kernel: [17438.686486] rfkill: input handler disabled
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-color[1169]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/home/sa/.local/share/icc/edid-72076249bd7ea37abad4c5c04b1d1cb6.icc”: Permission denied
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-power[21085]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-media-keys[21133]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-keyboard[21130]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-color[21122]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-wacom[21115]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7' unit='evolution-calendar-factory.service' requested by ':1.20' (uid=1000 pid=21027 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-calendar-server " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-clipboard[21121]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gnome-software[21174]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.locale1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.locale1.service' requested by ':1.17927' (uid=1000 pid=21130 comm="/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gsd-keyboard " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa systemd[1]: Starting Locale Service...
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa nautilus-deskto[21185]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.FileManager1' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=21185 comm="nautilus-desktop " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa nautilus[21219]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[821]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.locale1'
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa systemd[1]: Started Locale Service.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-xsettings[21108]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.FileManager1'
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gnome-shell[20985]: Error looking up permission: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.impl.portal.PermissionStore was not provided by any .service files
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.Calendar7'
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa systemd[20842]: Started Evolution calendar service.
Aug  2 20:39:17 sa gsd-color[1169]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/home/sa/.local/share/icc/edid-72076249bd7ea37abad4c5c04b1d1cb6.icc”: Permission denied
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa nautilus-deskto[21185]: Can not get _NET_WORKAREA
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa nautilus-deskto[21185]: Can not determine workarea, guessing at layout
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9' unit='evolution-addressbook-factory.service' requested by ':1.56' (uid=1000 pid=21235 comm="/usr/lib/evolution/evolution-calendar-factory-subp" label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Evolution address book service...
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolution.dataserver.AddressBook9'
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa systemd[20842]: Started Evolution address book service.
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa nautilus-deskto[21185]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa gnome-shell[20985]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa gnome-shell[20985]: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Metadata' unit='gvfs-metadata.service' requested by ':1.50' (uid=1000 pid=21185 comm="nautilus-desktop " label="unconfined")
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa systemd[20842]: Starting Virtual filesystem metadata service...
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa dbus-daemon[20866]: [session uid=1000 pid=20866] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Metadata'
Aug  2 20:39:18 sa systemd[20842]: Started Virtual filesystem metadata service.
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-software[21174]: plugin appstream took 1.5 seconds to do setup
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-software[21174]: enabled plugins: systemd-updates, packagekit-refine-repos, packagekit-upgrade, packagekit, packagekit-local, ubuntuone, os-release, packagekit-refresh, desktop-categories, shell-extensions, packagekit-proxy, packagekit-url-to-app, packagekit-offline, fwupd, appstream, ubuntu-reviews, packagekit-refine, hardcoded-popular, hardcoded-blacklist, rewrite-resource, steam, hardcoded-featured, desktop-menu-path, generic-updates, modalias, packagekit-history, snap, provenance, provenance-license, icons, key-colors, key-colors-metadata
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-software[21174]: disabled plugins: dpkg, repos, dummy, odrs, epiphany
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-software[21174]: failed to call gs_plugin_add_updates_historical on fwupd: failed to build result for cd273169181d707255b4afd0f0bec9fc898e557f
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-shell[20985]: GNOME Shell started at Thu Aug 02 2018 20:39:16 GMT+0500
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa PackageKit: get-updates transaction /481_beedabeb from uid 1000 finished with success after 545ms
Aug  2 20:39:19 sa gnome-software[21174]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Aug  2 20:39:20 sa PackageKit: resolve transaction /482_bddaacde from uid 1000 finished with success after 383ms
Aug  2 20:39:20 sa org.gnome.Shell.desktop[20985]: (google-chrome-stable:21304): Gtk-WARNING **: 20:39:20.899: Theme parsing error: gtk-main.css:73:38: Failed to import: Error opening file /usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-builder.css: No such file or directory
Aug  2 20:39:21 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /483_bedcaabc from uid 1000 finished with success after 516ms
Aug  2 20:39:21 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /484_ebebbddb from uid 1000 finished with success after 668ms
Aug  2 20:39:22 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /485_eeebaebe from uid 1000 finished with success after 764ms
Aug  2 20:39:23 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /486_cbcbceae from uid 1000 finished with success after 735ms
Aug  2 20:39:24 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /487_bdcdeacd from uid 1000 finished with success after 584ms
Aug  2 20:39:24 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /488_ebbdbbbd from uid 1000 finished with success after 588ms
Aug  2 20:39:25 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /489_dcecdbec from uid 1000 finished with success after 747ms
Aug  2 20:39:26 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /490_cdcdcccd from uid 1000 finished with success after 915ms
Aug  2 20:39:27 sa PackageKit: search-file transaction /491_daacabcb from uid 1000 finished with success after 1084ms
Aug  2 20:39:29 sa PackageKit: get-details transaction /492_bdcddbca from uid 1000 finished with success after 939ms
```

Solution:
After some play-arounds finally managed to fix. I just rebooted system theme. Specifically, the affect was either
Animatios,
icons, 
Cursor.

try to reload them

Comment: Disable all shell extensions, then try again. https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=GNOME-Shell-JS-Exts-Problems

Comment: @IporSircer thank you for your reply. I disabled extensions via gnome tweak. Still it did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: After some play-arounds finally managed to fix. I just rebooted system theme. Specifically, the affect was either
Animatios, icons, Cursor.

try to reload them